# Regex Match any Word in single or multiple lines [\r\n]

Tags: c#, .net, regex

We need to search the word "test.property" and replace "test1.field" in a single or multiple line.

word boundary won't ignore the `\r\n`, it can find the:

```
test.\r\nproperty
```

how to ignore the `\r\n` between words in regex C#?

ex:

Input sources:

```
int c = test\r\n.Property\r\n["Test"];
```

needed output :

```
int c = test1\r\n.Field\r\n["Test"];
```

My current output :

```
int c =test1.Field.["test"]
```

Pattern :

regex I'm using :

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\btest\s*\.\s*property\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
 replacementLine = regex.Replace(sourceLine, "test1.field");
```

we need to replace only the string not the line break. Please give your suggestions?

Comment: Note you have a typo in `propery`. Just `@"\btest\s*\.\s*property\b"` should do (this will remove the linebreak though). If you need the whitespace, `@"\btest(\s*\.\s*)property(\s*)"` to replace with `"test1$1field$2"`. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbtest(%5cs*%5c.%5cs*)property(%5cs*)&i=int+c+%3d+test.%0d%0a++++++++Property%0d%0a++++++++%5b%22Test%22%5d%3b%0d%0a%0d%0aint+c+%3d+test.Property%5b%22Test%22%5d%3b&r=test1%241field%242&o=i).

Comment: Please re-format the question so that it is clear what input you have.

Comment: whatever you told is correct, but i need to replace the string like
from int c = test.\r\nProperty\r\n["Test"]; to int c = test1\r\n.method\r\n["Test"] , we need just replace string not the line breaks

Comment: What is wrong with [`\btest(\s*\.\s*)property(\s*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbtest(%5cs*%5c.%5cs*)property(%5cs*)&i=c+%3d+test.%0d%0aProperty%0d%0a%5b%22Test%22%5d%3b&r=test1%241field%242&o=i)? Result is `c = test1.\r\n​field\r\n​["Test"];`

Comment: How to convert @"\btest\s*\.\s*property\b to \b + pattern + \b where pattern = test.property ? please give some suggestions

Comment: Do you also mean the replacements are variables? Are the strings to search and replace all have the same number of "subparts" separated with `.`? Please [check this demo](http://ideone.com/oeP0Jc), I think it is a bit more comprehensive than what you need, but should work unless you show more examples.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?'g1'\btest\b\.\W*)(?'g3'\bproperty\b)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
var replacementLine = regex.Replace(sourceLine, "${g1}Field");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a lookbehind which also accepts the *possible* whitespace. Here is an example which ignores the first, changes both the second and third findings.

```
var data = @"testNO.property['LeaveThis'];
test
.property
['Test'];

test.property['Test2'];";

var pattern = @"(?<=test[\r\n\s]*\.)property";

Regex.Replace(data, pattern, "field")
```

**Result of Replace**

```
testNO.property['LeaveThis']; 
test
.field
['Test'];

test.field['Test2'];
```